# How do you find what value a keyboard key has? (dwm keybinding)

Tags: keyboard, c, dwm

I'm setting up key bindings in dwm for things like changing brightness and taking screenshots. In order to bind the appropriate key, I followed someone else's example and added

```
#define XF86AudioMute 0x1008ff12
```

to my config.h, and referred to that key in my keybinding.

This works fine, but I have no idea where this value came from or how to find other similar values. For example, the `PrtSc` button on my keyboard is one that I haven't been able to find a value for.

What are these values, and how do I find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition

```
#define XF86AudioMute 0x1008ff12
```

comes from the header file `XF86keysym.h`, though it's spelled differently:

```
#define XF86XK_AudioMute        0x1008FF12   /* Mute sound from the system */
```

To find the keysyms that your keyboard sends, use `xev`.  Not all keys will send keysyms, however (in that case, you can't do much).

Further reading:

- [*What does this output from xev mean?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33355/what-does-this-output-from-xev-mean)